# Powershell does not recognize command -PassThru

Tags: powershell

I am using the `Expand-Archive` command to unzip some .zip files. I want this process to generate a log and I am trying to use the parameter -PassThru.

```
Expand-Archive D:\Users\user1\Desktop\Zip\de23.zip -DestinationPath D:\Users\user1\Desktop\result -Force -PassThru
```

Result:

> Expand-Archive : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
> name 'PassThru'.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: The `-PassThru` switch is not present in the version of the module that ships with Windows PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Use `-Verbose` instead.

Comment: The docs confusingly default to version 7.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing [Mathias's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74153514/7571258), here is a solution that uses the `-Verbose` switch to generate a log and then parses the file paths from this log to achieve the same output as with `-PassThru` on newer PowerShell versions:

```sh
Expand-Archive ZipFile.zip -DestinationPath C:\ExtractDir -Force -Verbose 4>&1 | 
    Select-String -Pattern "Created '(.+)'" | 
    Get-Item -Path { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

- `4>&1` redirects (merges) the *verbose* stream (created by `-Verbose`) into the *success* (standard output) stream, so we can process it by pipeline commands. See [About Output Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2).
- `Select-String` searches each line of output for the given RegEx pattern. See this [RegEx101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jIi5KP/1) for a detailed explanation and the ability to experiment.
- In the `Get-Item` line the path is specified through a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters). This script block extracts the value of the 1st group (the file path) from the current RegEx match.
- `Get-Item` outputs a [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0) object, similar to what `Expand-Archive -PassThru` on newer PowerShell versions produces. This causes the default PowerShell formatter to produce the familiar directory listing.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the documentation you're referencing is for the *latest* version of PowerShell. For the last version of **Windows** PowerShell (version 5.1), the `-PassThru` switch is not present.

To work around this you can use the underlying .NET API to "manually" unpack the archive:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression

$destination = "C:\destination\folder"

# Define log file name
$logFileName = "unpack-archive.log"

# Locate zip file
$zipFile = Get-Item C:\path\to\file.zip

"[$(Get-Date -F o)][INFO] Opening '$($zipFile.FullName)' to expand" |Add-Content $logFileName

# Open a read-only file stream
$zipFileStream = $zipFile.OpenRead()

# Instantiate ZipArchive
$zipArchive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]::new($zipFileStream)

# Iterate over all entries and pick the ones you like
foreach($entry in $zipArchive.Entries){
    try {
        "[$(Get-Date -F o)][INFO] Attempting to create '$($entry.Name)' in '${destination}'" |Add-Content $logFileName

        # Create new file on disk, open writable stream
        $targetFileStream = $(
            New-Item -Path $destination -Name $entry.Name -ItemType File
        ).OpenWrite()

        "[$(Get-Date -F o)][INFO] Attempting to copy '$($entry.Name)' to target file" |Add-Content $logFileName
        # Open stream to compressed file, copy to new file stream
        $entryStream = $entry.Open()
        $entryStream.BaseStream.CopyTo($targetFileStream)
    }
    catch {
        "[$(Get-Date -F o)][ERROR] Failed to unpack '$($entry.Name)': ${_}" |Add-Content $logFileName
    }
    finally {
        # Clean up
        $targetFileStream,$entryStream |ForEach-Object Dispose
    }
}

# Clean up
$zipArchive,$zipFileStream |ForEach-Object Dispose
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$entryStream.CopyTo($targetFileStream)` instead of `$entryStream.BaseStream.CopyTo($targetFileStream)` ? // I think `New-Item -Path (Join-Path $destination $entry.FullName) -Force` would also be nice to handle possible folders